# SDMs in R problems with Java Memory `

Tags: java, r, rjava

I have tried using this command to increase the memory availability for running MaxEnt in R :

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx1g" )
```

as suggested by the dismo pacakge to increase the access to RAM but this then leads to a new error:

```
"Error in .jinit() : Cannot create Java virtual machine (-1)"
```

has anyone resolved this issue? Any advice would help.

Cheers
Israel

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that my work machine is running a 32 bit Operating system and to run rJava effectively you need a 64 system set up.